# Does iOS API provide gestures a property for the amount of surface contact when activated?

Tags: ios6, uigesturerecognizer

Can you detect the amount of surface contact (CGFloat) of a press in iOS? That is, the area of contact between the finger and the screen, or are you limited to detecting CGPoint?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, iOS only supports five concurrent touches, each represented by a point. Once a sixth finger hits the screen, `touchesEnded:` isn't called for the initial touch (you can break a lot of drawers and other sliding UI elements this way). To measure surface area, you'd need numerous points. Gestures are merely ways of abstracting out logic for handling touches, and nothing in the [UITouch docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html) suggests that touches can be represented by more than a single location in a view.

But that's definitely an interesting idea. While you wouldn't be able to measure the size of a fingerprint, you would be able to detect the size of a pinched area between three to five points assuming the area to be an n-gon with vertices at n touch locations. Or, you can assume the two furthest points to be opposing points on a diameter of a circle--that type of thing.

Alternatively, you can *assume* the area of an average fingerprint to be a certain value and approximate combinations of touches that way, perhaps filling in any interior space?